# How to make empty placeholder tests intentionally fail in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing an API in NodeJS and testing using Mocha, Chai and SuperTest. I'm using a typical test-driven approach of writing the tests first then satisfying those tests with working code. However, because of the number of tests for all the different permutations, I've started writing empty placeholder tests so that I have all the `it('should...')` descriptions in place to remind me what to test when I get to that feature. For example:

```
it 'should not retrieve documents without an authorized user', (done) ->
    done()
```

The problem with this is that `done()` is called without any assertion so the test is considered passing, so I've added the following assertion.

```
false.should.equal true # force failure
```

but it's a hack and the reason for failure that Mocha displays can seem confusing, especially when other full tests might be failing.

Is there any official way to intentionally fail placeholder tests like this in Mocha?

Comment: I don't know of any official way, but for something like this I would think to use the [should library](https://github.com/tj/should.js) and do something like `should.fail('not yet implemented')` .  Maybe wrap that in your own module/function and reuse it throughout your tests.  In Chai, the only thing I can think would be to wrap some thrown error , but that would probably look pretty ugly.

Comment: @JustinMaat Sadly chai's implementation of should has no `fail()` method. Perhaps I might consider switching assertion libraries.

Comment: I don't know if I'd switch actual libraries.  Looking through the docs I see a fail() function under the [assert section](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/) .  This is actually a very good question as I'd find this useful as well :)  I'll try to get a gist and submit an actual answer here soon

Comment: @JustinMaat `assert.fail()` would probably be a suitable answer since it doesn't require any modules to change.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The official way to mark tests as not being ready for testing yet is to use `skip`, which is a method that appears as a field of `describe` and `it`. Here's an example:

```
describe("not skipped", function () {
    it("bar", function () {
        throw new Error("fail");
    });

    it.skip("blah", function () {
        throw new Error("fail");
    });
});

describe.skip("skipped", function () {
    it("something", function () {
        throw new Error("fail");
    });
});
```

The above code, when put in a `test.js` file and run with `$ mocha --reporter=spec test.js`, produces:

```
  not skipped
    1) bar
    - blah

  skipped
    - something


  0 passing (4ms)
  2 pending
  1 failing

  1) not skipped bar:
     Error: fail
      at Context.<anonymous> (/tmp/t33/test.js:3:15)
      at callFn (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:223:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:216:7)
      at Runner.runTest (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:374:10)
      at /home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:452:12
      at next (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:299:14)
      at /home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:309:7
      at next (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:247:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/home/ldd/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:276:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
```

The test names that are preceded by `-` are skipped. Also, in a terminal that supports colors the tests that are skipped appear in blue (by opposition to red for failed tests and green for passing). A skipped test is said to be "pending" so Mocha reports the number of skipped tests as "2 pending".

Comment: Thanks for this, I was not aware of skip.  However, after reading the docs this seems to just be a way to literally "skip" a test.  While useful, I think the OP wants a canonical way to make it Fail, ie, the code you have here -  `throw new Error("fail");`  In that case, I don't see any way within the framework itself to do this.  Some other languages/frameworks have this feature (ex: scala has ??? placeholder)

Comment: upvoting, because after thinking about it, this is probably much better since it clearly marks the test as a placeholder.  I'd probably implement a not-yet-ready function like i have above for actual implementation code.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed my chosen answer (sorry @JustinMaat) since this technically is what I wanted to do and it's more official.

Comment: Best solution I think. The pending works only if you don't want to implement the tests, but in my case I want to write the tests first and implement the features later one by one. The only thing that worries me here that it does not write why those tests were skipped, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 31):

As of 05/19/2018 this is the official way: https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests

An unimplemented test shouldn't `fail`, it should be marked as `pending`.

A succinct method of marking a mocha test as `not yet implemented` is to not pass a callback function to the `it` handler.

```
describe("Traverse", function(){
    describe("calls the visitor function", function(){
        it("at every element inside an array")
        it("at every level of a tree")
    })
})
```

Running `mocha test` will display your unimplemented tests as pending.

```
$ mocha test

  Traverse
    calls the visitor function
      - at every element inside an array
      - at every level of a tree


  0 passing (13ms)
  2 pending
```

Answer (score 8):

If you pass a string or error to `done()` it will report it as an error. So:

```
it 'should not retrieve documents without an authorized user', (done) ->
    done('not implemented')
```

would cause the test to fail with the output:

> done() invoked with non-Error: not implemented

---

I like @Canyon's solution of just not passing a callback to mark the tests "pending", but in my case I want these placeholders to fail my CI builds, so making them actual failing tests like this was easier.

Comment: Even better: Add an `new Error( 'reason' )` object.

Comment: This also helps a lot when using Promises or Rx Observables that will swallow any errors thrown using `throw`.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a good question because I would also find this super useful.  After looking at it, I would think to just create your own wrapper "todo" or "fail" function that you can reuse throughout your codebase.

Examples below use a function called todo, which will print out the text "not yet implemented".  This might be useful as a separate module even so you can import and use with all your tests.  Might need to modify the code a bit...

Example in chai assert

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;

function todo() {
    assert(false, "method not yet implemented"); 
};

describe("some code", function(){
    it("should fail something", function(){
        todo();
    });
});
```

Example using chai assert , with the fail option (although it looks unncessary)

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;

function todo() {
    assert.fail(true, true, "method not yet implemented");   //1st 2 args can be anything really
};

describe("some code", function(){
    it("should fail something", function(){
        todo();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've put in a feature request to have the `.fail()` method added to all styles in Chai so hopefully this gets updated in the future https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/350

Comment: Just to save people a click, looks like this pull request was accepted a while back so you can use .fail() now.

Comment: Does not make much sense. If you write all the tests first and write the code later, then you want mocha to skip all your tests and stay green. Otherwise it is hard to find the feature you are working on from all the failing tests. You won't be able to commit and push with failing tests either depending on how you do those things.